# If you put a MOSFET in backwards does the impedance change?

Tags: mosfet, diodes, capacitance

if I stick a MOSFET that should be going (S-D) to positive in **backwards**, and make it (D-S) to positive, all the current drops across the diode instead. This diode then approaches an impedance of 0.

Technically the current wouldn't go through the higher impedance S-D capacitance, and wants to travel through the diode instead.

Can I ignore the capacitance of source-drain while the voltage drops across the diode?

(I know this is not a ~practical~ thing, but I'm wondering more about the diode versus S-D capacitance than the practicality of backwards FETs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case of a diode. Diodes have a low "resistive" impedance (i.e., current is in phase with voltage), and they also have capacitance. At low frequencies most of the current flows through the diode resistively, and at high frequencies most current flows through the capacitance.

When the S-D of a MOSFET is biased backwards, it's exactly the same thing. It's a diode.

Be mindful that under forward bias, a diode has more capacitance than under reverse bias. Namely, the capacitance (called a "diffusion capacitance") scales linearly with the DC current. Therefore, *the frequency at which capacitive current dominates resistive current* remains roughly constant regardless of DC current level.

To answer your question of whether you can ignore the source-drain capacitance: It depends on the frequency of interest.

In the synchronous FET of a switching converter (which is where you'll usually see a FET with reverse S-D bias), you do care about this capacitance. In this context though, because the behavior is large-signal and the frequencies are so high to cause non-quasistatic behavior, it's usually called something different: [*reverse recovery charge*](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/technical-articles/Understanding-Diode-Reverse-Recovery-and-Its-Effect-on-Switching-Losses.pdf). This emphasizes that in this context, thinking of the diode as a simple conductance or capacitance is incomplete.

Comment: So if I put a couple back to back, and ran AC through the two MOSFETs (so basically an SSR), since they both are reverse/forward biased at either end of the cycle, I can just use the datasheet specific value of c charge at V(sd)? http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOK42S60.pdf (120kHz)

Comment: I think I'm still kind of confused. The datasheet specifies a a value of 100pF S-D at 1Mhz, which is WAY higher than my 120kHz, so I could just use the constant capacitance of 100pF (Figure 9) across S-D, right? Why bother with the reverse recovery charge if at 600V the S-D capacitance is still relatively constant at 1MHz.

Comment: Also, if I'm operating at 120kHz, my MOSFET SSR will have an impedance of around 13,000; will it be able to stop, or dampen, the AC if I turn it off? Rds on is 0.099, and Rds off is simply the 13000 from the capacitor.

Comment: I don't think you got my point. 100pF is the *reverse-biased* capacitance. Its forward-biased capacitance manifests itself as a reverse-recovery charge (\$Q_{RR}\$ -- it's in the electrical characteristics table as 10μC). As for the impedance of a 100pF capacitor being 13kΩ, it's not meaningful to think of things that way. Not for a switching converter with a switching frequency of 120kHz anyway.

Comment: Well see I understand that it's the reverse-biased C, but my two MOSFETs are standing back-to-back in AC as a relay with the anodes connected; so **isn't there only ever reverse-bias** on them? (Otherwise the current could just run through the FET and not the diode) As for the impedance thing, again, what if it's in an SSR configuration, and it's only getting a signal on/off once every two or three seconds. Similar to; http://i.stack.imgur.com/5tW9S.png

Comment: I see. I was presuming you cared about switching converters, since 120kHz is a pretty typical switching frequency. In this case, yes, ~100pF is the capacitance you care about.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the 130kHz/600V sinusoid coming from?

Comment: From a H-bridge that draws from a bridge-rectifier that draws from isolated mains.

Comment: I kind of wanted to know if the 100pF would have enough impedance to block the AC when the MOSFETs are off. 600 Volts / 13000 R gives me 0.04A, which is very low in comparison to the 0.5A this circuit would be drawing; but does it count as 'blocked'?

Comment: In other words, how do I know when an AC signal is even 'blocked'? It seems like current would just go through anyway. Is it at -40dB relative to the unimpeded signal or something?

Comment: Sorry for the billions of messages; R(DS) is 0.1~, so if I've got the C(DS) down to 100pF, it should be almost completely blocked. 0.05A * 0.1R = 0.005 Volts on the S-D terminals. I'm totally fine as long as I operate at >130V, where C(SD) becomes 100pF, right?.

Comment: What you consider "blocked" is up to you. There's no universal definition. Some people might consider 20dB reduction blocked. Some might require 40dB. Depends on the application.

Comment: So if I wanted to use this to resonantly tune a tank circuit, this is about the blocking I would need to have my SSR act as an actual switch.